# Continuous Phase Modulation - Phase trajectory expansion

Tags: modulation, integration, proof

For continuous phase modulation (CPM), the circular phase trajectory is expressed as follows:

$$\phi(t) = 2\pi h\int_0^t\sum_k \xi_k g(\tau - kT_s)d\tau + \Phi_0\tag{1.1}$$

Where:

- $h$ is the modulation index, a constant
- $\xi_k$ is the symbol time at time $kT_s$
- $g(t)$ is a frequency pulse shape with duration $LT_s$

From [Digital Radio Systems on a Chip - A Systems Approach, P88](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b117276) equation (1.1) above is expanded in terms of the phase pulse shape $q(t)=\int g(\tau)d\tau$ to give the following:

$$\phi(t;\xi_k,\sigma_k) = 2\pi h\xi_k q(t - kT_s)d\tau + 2\pi h\sum_{i=k-L+1}^{k-1}\xi_i q(t - iT_s) +\pi h\sum_{i=0}^{k-L}\xi_i + \Phi_0\tag{1.2}$$

Where:

- $\xi_k$ is the current $k^{\text{th}}$ symbol
- $\sigma_k$ is the modulator state at time $kT_s$, denoting a set of phase values of the CPM signal traversed up to time $kT_s$
- $q(t) = \begin{cases}0, & t \leq 0 \\ 
  \displaystyle \int_0^t g(\tau)d\tau, & 0 \leq t \leq LT_s\\ 
  \frac 12, & t>LT_s\end{cases}\tag{1.3}$

My understanding is that the second and last terms in equation (1.2) come from equating $q(t)$ to the cases $0\leq t\leq LT_s$ and $t>LT_s$ respectively. Even though I see that the three RHS terms in equation (1.2) are for $i = k$, $i = k-L+1, k-L+2, \ldots, k-1$, and $i = 0, 1, \ldots, k-L$ respectively; I am lost on the integration/summation exchanges.

I'd appreciate all help in understanding the integral-sum and indexes manipulation in deriving (1.2).